# How to update BIOS from lenovo after migrating from Win 11 to Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, bios, lenovo-laptop

Is it possible to update the BIOS from Lenovo after migrating from Win 11 OS to Linux OS (Vanilla Debian in this case)? It's not dual-booted so grub is changed as my whole SSD is used for this Linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

See Debian
[Firmware Updates](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware/Updates) :

Linux Vendor Firmware Service

> [fwupd](https://fwupd.org/) utilizes a firmware database to fetch missing updates for your system and peripherals. Currently the [vendor](https://fwupd.org/vendorlist) and [device](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist) coverage is not too broad but it is a good starting point before you dive into vendor specific update procedures.

See also
[How to update Lenovo BIOS from Linux without using Windows](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-lenovo-bios-from-linux-usb-stick-pen/):

> 1. Download Lenovo BIOS Bootable CD for your Laptop model
> 2. Use the geteltorito command to extract bootable image
> 3. Run the dd command to write extracted image to USB stick or pen
> 4. Reboot the laptop
> 5. Interrupt boot process by pressing the ENTER key
> 6. Press F12 key and select USB mass storage device as boot source
> 7. The BIOS update utility should run now

More details to be found in the article.

Note that you should be very careful with the BIOS version
that you choose to install, so as not to make unfortunate errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Bios file from the Lenovo site then extract the Bios file in a Windows device, transfer the file to your device, reboot and enter BIOS, update the BIOS from the file.

But be aware this act is very risky!

Don't do it if you are not sure about that!

Also, you can use bootable mini Windows to boot from it and execute EXE BIOS file.

Comment: You don't need a Windows device to extract it.